# Association with alias \"reservations\" does not exist on reservations"

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, associations

I'm trying to associate my reservation table to my schedule table but I'm not sure what this error means Association with alias "reservations" does not exist on reservations" Thank you very much

Associations

```
// USER AND ERRANDS Associations
db.schedule.hasMany(db.reservations, { as: "reservations" });
db.reservations.belongsTo(db.schedule, {
 foreignKey: "scheduleID",
 as: "schedule"
});
```

Reservation Model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const Reservation = sequelize.define('reservations', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    userID: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    scheduleID: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    date: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
});

return Reservation;
```

};

Schedule Model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const Schedule = sequelize.define('schedules', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    timein: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    timeout: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    slot: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    statuss: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
});

return Schedule;
```

};

My Controller

```
exports.ScheduleReservation = async function (req, res, next) {

try {
    var reservation = await ReservationService.ScheduleReservation({include: ["reservations"]})
    return res.status(200).json({ status: 200, data: reservation, message: "Succesfully Users Retrieved" });
} catch (e) {
    return res.status(400).json({ status: 400, message: e.message });
}
```

}

Comment: Did you solve this since then? What was wrong or missing?